# MySQL Get Value On hour At specific date

Tags: mysql

My Table looks as follows:

```
(int)Epoch, (string)Price
12345, 123.22
12346, 111.33
12347, 119.44
13211, 100.44
13255, 120.05
…
```

I need to be able to get the Price value at given hour and date.
Example: GetPriceAt("12/01/2015 16:00")

If there is value exactly at 12/01/2015 16:00 then return it, if there isn't return the previous value in the table.
Example:

```
12/01/2015 13:00, 123.22
12/01/2015 13:01, 111.33
12/01/2015 13:50, 119.44
12/01/2015 14:10, 100.44
12/01/2015 14:15, 120.05
```

GetPriceAt("12/01/2015 14:00") - would return 119.44 (price from 13:50)

GetPriceAt("12/01/2015 13:00") - would return 123.22 (we had this one)

How do i query the MySQL?
Thanks very much

Comment: For case `GetPriceAt("12/01/2015 16:00")` shouldn't the resultant price will be `120.05` instead of 119 ?

Comment: there you go [`demo`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2d05d/4)

Comment: thx mate, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

(not pretty and not tested)

```
select * from
( select * from <your table> order by <date column> desc ) as q0
where <date column> <= <some value> limit 1
```

Comment: Why the subquery? Just use `select * from table where date <= 'datestamp' order by date desc limit 1`

Comment: Overkill - just wanted to make sure the dates were in the correct order

Comment: Also - the OP wants the `<=` rather than `>`

Comment: @ethrbunny there is no need for sub query [see demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2d05d/4)

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid - your demo is returning "14:15" - should be returning "13:50" - but I see your point.